# Active Record :includes with limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a table of Articles which have many Images

The images are sorted for each Article with the first ordered image intended to be the article thumbnail.

In the Article controller index method I am currently doing the the following to limit to 2 active record queries;

```
@articles = Article.where(:active => true).includes(:images)
```

And to access the thumbnail:

```
# article model
def thumb
 self.images.first if self.images
end
```

Problem is this is only 2 queries, but if each article has 10 images and i have 50 articles on each page then ive loaded 500 image rows into memory.

Is there a more effective way of doing this in active record. Was hoping not to have to use find_by_sql

Comment: What are the images ordered by?

Comment: ive got a column called ordinal which is just an int, so i want them to be ordered by ordinal ASC, and really i only care about the first one which is the thumb (ordinal = 1). thanks

Comment: See @Delba's updated answer. His new solution is better than the one I proposed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**2 queries**

```
@articles = Article.where(:active => true).includes(:thumb)

# app/model/article.rb
has_one :thumb, :class_name => 'Image',
                :conditions => { :ordinal => 1 }
```

**1 query**

*Don't use this solution if some articles don't have thumb*

If you want to specify a condition on the joined table, maybe you should use `joins` instead of `includes`:

```
@articles = Article.joins(:images)
                   .where(:active => true, 
                          :images => { :ordinal => 1 })
                   .includes(:images)
```

It loads only the images where `:ordinal => 1`

I hope it helps

**The difference between** `joins` and `includes` when specifying conditions on eager loaded associations:

"Even though Active Record lets you specify conditions on the eager loaded associations just like joins, the recommended way is to use joins instead.

[...]

`includes` generate a query which contains a LEFT OUTER JOIN whereas the `joins` method would generate one using the INNER JOIN function instead." For further help see [the Specifying Conditions on Eager Loaded Associations section in Active Record Query Interface Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations).

Comment: Great answer and simple approach.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant, unless I'm just thinking about it wrong, this approach doesn't solve ADAM's problem at all (this was actually my first idea, but then after thinking about it, I revised it and posted my other hackier-but-working answer here). This solution has two big problems: (1) It will not select articles that have no associated images. (2) Furthermore, it won't actually solve the initial problem of limiting both number of queries and number of objects. It still loads all the images into memory, not just the thumbnail. The image join condition only limits the result set of the articles.

Comment: @BenLee Do you have something to show me? Because I tried before posting and didn't see any problems: /// There is only 1 query not matter how many articles you've got. /// Only the articles where `condition` (in this case `ordinal: 1`) are loaded (one per article). /// The (1) may be a problem if some articles don't have thumb, you're right.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, This worked perfectly but unfortunately i need a way to also show the Articles with no thumbs.

Comment: Your updated answer is very elegant; I didn't think of adding a new association for thumb, but it makes complete sense though. I think the OP should change this to the accepted answer.

Comment: @BenLee thanks for your fair-play Ben Lee, I would accept these precious points with joy! ;-)

Comment: has_one doesn’t accept :conditions anymore (since Rails 4, I think). The scope should be passed as the second parameter: `has_one :thumb, -> { where(ordinal: 1) }, class_name: 'Image'`

Answer (score 3):

This isn't the cleanest, but you can keep this down to 2 queries by selecting all images associated with the selected articles that have ordinal 1, like this:

```
@articles = Article.where(:active => true).all
images = Image.where(:article_id => @articles.map(&:id), :ordinal => 1).all
```

The won't link the objects together though. You can make `thumb` an attribute accessor though instead of a method, like this:

```
# article model
attr_accessor :thumb
```

Then when you are loading your images like above, you could set the thumb attribute after:

```
@articles = Article.where(:active => true).all
images = Image.where(:article_id => @articles.map(&:id), :ordinal => 1).all
images_hash = images.each_with_object({}) { |img, h| h[img.article_id] = img }
@articles.each { |article| article.thumb = images_hash[article.id] }
```

That's one way to do it. UPDATE: Improved efficiency of above code per @Axsuul's suggestion in the comments.

Another way, if you know that every article will have at least one image, is to come at from the images side. Select all images with ordinal 1, and include the articles. Like this:

```
@articles = Image.include(:article).where('images.ordinal' => 1, 'articles.active' => true).map(&:article)
```

Comment: might work but not a fan of having a .map and a .select in there for general maintainability. prefer Delba solution.  but will not -1 as is different approach that some might prefer if stronger in Ruby.

Comment: Thanks, Option 1 works perfectly. Agree that it feels like a bit of hack to use .map but it's actually pretty cunning the way you've stored the thumb back in the listing, and its much cleaner than what i was originally doing. Would rather run with this than find_by_sql, Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Axsuul, what do you mean exactly? Put them in a hash where?

Comment: And to whoever down-voted me, care to explain? What did I miss?

Comment: Like instead store the images within `images_hash = images.each_with_object({}) { |img, h| h[img.article_id] = img }` then you can retrieve the image by calling `images_hash[article.id]`.